# Using pointers in Class Templates with Subclasses

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates, subclass

I have a problem with using pointers with Class templates. I can't properly access `vv` from the `B` subclass if 'vv' stores pointers to vectors; if I simply store vectors it works. But what I'm trying to do requires me to store pointers. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong so here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
    public:
        std::vector<std::vector<T>*> vv;
        void add(std::vector<T> new_vec)
        {
            vv.push_back(&new_vec);
        }

        virtual void print(){}
        virtual ~A(){}
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>{
    public:
        void print() override{
            std::cout << this->vv[0]->at(0) << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(i);
    
    A <int>*a = new B<int>();
    a->add(v);
    a->print();
    return 0;
}
```

`a->print()` prints `0` instead of `10`. Also I can't change what is inside `main()`.
I would be very thankful for some help!

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant to write. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    void add(std::vector<T> new_vec)
    {
        vv.push_back(&new_vec);
    }
```

You store a pointer to the local argument `new_vec` in `vv`. That local copy will only live till the method returns. Hence the pointers in the vector are useless. Dereferencing them later invokes undefined behavior. If you really want to store pointers you should pass a pointer (or reference) to `add`. Though, you should rather use smart pointers.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this while still keeping 'a -> add(v)' as is?

Comment: @boionbike The "(or reference)" part of this answer allows it to be used without changing the syntax of `a->add(v);`.

Comment: Thank you all! I get it now, I was a bit confused.